# Sending response from a server android

Tags: android, android-emulator

my code sends latitude a longitude to server as parameters to a servlet.
In server it calculates the nearest distance to a branch and should send back an whole data of information like City Name, Address, latitude and longitude of branches. I have all of these information in database in server and I am also getting ordered list upon distance.

But how to send this list as an response from server to a device and how shall I collect this data from the response in android. Any help with code example would be helpful. thanks.

Comment: Not sure what exactly is the problem here. You have to serialize your response somehow - xml or json - and send it back to your client. There you have to deserialize it in order to access the information. In order to deal with xml or json, there are plenty of libraries available

Comment: @axel any links for the sending of response json or xml and accessing in android. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

at the server side you need to create a class with name resulatanClass  & make all the datamember that you are going to return. now return this class in your response. Or the alternate way is you can send them in XML format & at the android app side you need to parse then while receiving it.

Answer (score 1):

You should try creating a web service for this. A web service is like a public function that you can call over the net. The response of the web service can be in XML form. The android device must connect to the web service and wait for its response and then parse the response accordingly.

A web service has its own link so it's just like connecting to a URL and waiting for its response.

Sample Web Service Call:

```
httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL("http://webServiceURL/webServiceMethod")).openConnection()); //connect to the url of the web service
console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream())); //get the response of the web service
```

Sample Web Service Method:

```
public String webServiceMethod(String argumento)
{
    String response;
    //set response value here depending on the value of the parameter
    return response; //yes, returning a response in web service is as straightforward as this
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for that.

If you just want to send a simple object you can do the following:

1: create an object that holds the data you want to transfer

```
class MyDataObject {
  private String cityname, address;
  private double longitude, latitude;

  MyDataObject() {
    // no-args constructor
  }
}
```

2: create your JSON response string that you send back in your HTTP response

```
MyDataObject data = new MyDataObject();
// set values
Gson gson = new Gson();
String responseData = gson.toJson(data);
// put this string in your response
```

3: read response on your Android client

```
String responseData;
// read response string

Gson gson = new Gson();
MyDataObject data = gson.fromJson(responseData,MyDataObject.class);
// access the data stored in your object
```

You can also send arrays or other more complex objects using JSON. If you want to use google-gson for this you should take a look at [GSON User Guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

-axel

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you build a JSON string which will contain all the information and do a HTTP POST request from the android and get back the results.

Using the data retrieved from the server parse the JSON and use the data you need in the views.